# how to cache the pnpm store and the node modules in gitlab cicd

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

hello guys I have a working pipeline that take 3 to 4 minutes to finish and I noticed that the publish stage always installs the dependencies even if the `package.json` did not change and that's my `gitlab ci`

```
variables:
  # Define a variable for the cache key based on the hash of the package.json file
  CACHE_KEY: './apps/backend-manager/package.json'

cache:
  key: ${CACHE_KEY}
  paths:
    - ~/.local/share/pnpm/store  // i want to cache the pnpm store
    - 'node_modules' //I want to cache the node modules

backend-manager-build:
  image: docker:20.10.17
  stage: build
  services:
    - name: docker:20.10.17-dind
      alias: some
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: some
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ''
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"
      changes:
        - $BACKEND_MANAGER_RULES_CHANGES_PATH
  script:
    - docker login -u $CI_DEPLOY_USER -p $CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    # - docker pull $TAG_LATEST_BACKEND_MANAGER || true --cache-from $TAG_LATEST_BACKEND_MANAGER
    - docker build -f $BACKEND_MANAGER_DOCKERFILE_PATH  -t $TAG_LATEST_BACKEND_MANAGER .
    - docker push $TAG_LATEST_BACKEND_MANAGER
```

and that's my docker file

```
FROM node:alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm i -g pnpm
RUN pnpm install

COPY . .

RUN pnpm build:nbm

FROM node:alpine As production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm i -g pnpm
RUN pnpm install --prod

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD [ "node", "./dist/apps/backend-manager/main" ]
```

and that the log of the pipeline in the build stage

```
Saving cache for successful job
00:01
Creating cache ./apps/backend-manager/package.json-protected...
WARNING: ~/.local/share/pnpm/store: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (/builds/some/path) 
WARNING: node_modules: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (/builds/some/path) 
Archive is up to date!                             
Created cache
```

my goal is to cache the  `node_modules` folder and skip package installation if the `package.json` hasn't change since the previous pipeline run if not then install the packages normally

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the logs :

```
WARNING: ~/.local/share/pnpm/store: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (/builds/some/path) 
WARNING: node_modules: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (/builds/some/path)
```

GitLab couldn't find the directories to cache for two reasons :

- You're not installing the dependencies in your job and therefore not creating the cache folders. You're only building the image using docker-in-docker, which is why the folders are missing. GitLab will try to look for the cache folders in the job's container and not the image you're building using docker-in-docker.
- [Paths](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cachepaths) are relative from the directory where the job is being run on the GitLab runner, therefore it might have trouble finding the `~/.local/share/pnpm/store`.

On top of that, you're not copying the cache folders in your Dockerfile, so you won't be able to speed up your dependencies installation inside you Docker image.

You need to create the cache in a separate basic GitLab CI job that will install the dependencies, compress the `node_modules` folder to a `.tgz` and cache the archive using the `cache` directive.

One strategy would be to run that job every time the `package.json` or the `pnpm-lock.yaml` change, using [rules.changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges). Make sure it has the [push cache policy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cachepolicy) so it only updates the cache.

Also, use the `package.json` and the `pnpm-lock.yaml` as keys for your cache to invalidate it as soon as one of your dependencies or your Node version changes.

Finally, pull the cache in your docker-in-docker job using `cache.policy: pull` and add directives in your Dockerfile to copy the `node_modules.tgz` archive in the image. Little tip here, use `ADD node_*.tgz` as it will not fail if no cache was found (because one of your dependencies/node version was updated) and will uncompress the archive.